# Excel VBA: to export selected sheets to a single pdf, Excel doesn't export other than first sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I've tried several methods to include a selection of sheets, and then export to pdf. Each time only the first sheet turns out to be included in the pdf-file. 
What I'm trying to achieve is:
1. Select sheets manually
2. Run the macro. The macro will: 1. Export the selected sheets to a single pdf. 2. Deselect the selected sheets (to later avoid unintentionally editing across the selected sheets.)

```
 Sub Export_Selected_Sheets_To_PDF()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim PDF_Name, Doc_ID, Excel_Name, SelectedSheets() As String
    Dim n, i As Long
    Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Code for naming the PDF (equals excel filename including a prefix from a cell named "DocID")
    'Will be saved at same location as the excel-file
    Doc_ID = Range("DocID").Value                           'DocID = named cell in the WS
    Excel_Name = fso.GetBaseName(ActiveWorkbook.FullName)    'Excel filename without file extension
    PDF_Name = Doc_ID & "_" & Excel_Name & ".pdf"            'PDF filename

    'Showing the PDF_Name
    Debug.Print PDF_Name

    'Code for selecting the "selected" sheets
    n = 0
    For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
        ReDim Preserve SelectedSheets(n)
        SelectedSheets(n) = ws.Name
        n = n + 1
    Next

    'Showing the list of selected sheets
    For i = LBound(SelectedSheets) To UBound(SelectedSheets)
        Debug.Print SelectedSheets(i)
    Next i

    'Export selected sheets to pdf
    Sheets(SelectedSheets).Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDF_Name, Quality:= _
    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True

    'Deactivate selection to avoid editing across selected sheets.
    ActiveSheet.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: What errors are you getting when running this macro? On which line? Have you tried using debug to step through the macro command-by-command?

Comment: I do not get any errors, but the pdf-file includes the first sheet only, and not the other sheets that are selected. Seems to me that the code doesn't pay attention to "Sheets(SelectedSheets).Select", but "ActiveSheet" only.

Comment: Solved: The macro will work if the selected sheets have defined "Print_Areas". If not the macro has to include some lines defining the print_areas in each sheet (as in answer-post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the post
[Excel VBA to Export Selected Sheets to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20751096/165358)
was proposed the same method as yours.

However, further testing has shown that this technique depends on the group of
cells being **selected** on each worksheet.

The code was then modified to something like:

```
Sub Macro1()

   Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
   ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
   Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
   ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
   Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
   ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select

   ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select
   Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
      "C:\Users\James\Desktop\pdfmaker.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
      IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
      True
End Sub
```

This answer was highly upvoted, so might help in your case.

Comment: It certainly helped in getting to understand the problem. The original macro didn't work because only the first sheet had a defined "Print_Area". It worked after I had set print areas in the other sheets.